# AltUnityDriver create-Failed to execute command 'mobiledevice tunnel -u (device udid)13000 13000'

Tags: java, ios, xcode, macos, appium

**Env:** macOS Catalina, iOS 12.4.1 (for 13.3.1 the same), Xcode 11.4, Appium 17.0.0
**Issue:**
When trying to run method 'AltUnityDriver create' -  Failed to execute command 'mobiledevice tunnel -u (device udid) 13000 13000'. Cause 'java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory'.
Script fails when trying to run the command `new Socket(127.0.0.1, 13000);`

```
Method threw 'java.net.ConnectException' exception.
Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Test created for app with AltUnityDriver inside and it is needed to create connection

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your application is having AltUnityServer inside the app at the port 13000.
Then you have to port forward the phone port 13000 to the localhost.
Use command iproxy for the same. Syntax as follows:

```
iproxy LOCAL_PORT:DEVICE_PORT
```

Comment: only see a message "waiting for connection"

Comment: @Thejus Do we need to setup server in Eclipse in order to use AltUnityDriver ?I have added dependencies into my pom.xml. Wouldn't that solve the issue ?

Comment: The server has to be running inside the iOS application. First integrate the server along with your IPA. Then install the IPA on the device. After that run iproxy command to port forward iOS port to the host MAC. Only after this step is done, AltUnityDriver will get connected for running automation. Eclipse is just an IDE.